# No logs after running Zookeeper and kafka serer in Windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am also facing the same issue, when I start zookeeper didn't get any error or logs just blank. Could you please anybody help me to resolve.

in zookeeper.properties(folder temp I have manually created):

dataDir=F:/kafka_2.12-3.4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqyAQ.png).0/temp/zookeeper

After running the zookeeper I should get the logs